# Google Cloud Functions: How to setup Intellij (or other IDE) to have Code completion with NodeJS8

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, ide, google-cloud-functions

I'm starting with Google Cloud Functions (triggered by pub/sub), and I'm looking how to setup IntelliJ (Ultimate) or use another IDE to have syntax highlighting, code completion.

Do you know if it's possible with IntelliJ or another IDE?

My goal is to have a decent development environment and have the sources on Github.

I've been able to setup a correct project layout for github integration here : [Google Cloud Functions: Project layout for Github publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823074/google-cloud-functions-project-layout-for-github-publishing)

I do have syntax highlighting working, but the code completion is currently the basic javascript. Libraires are not integrated in code completion.

Comment: If you want something close to an IDE experience, I think you will be better off with VS Code and TypeScript (rather than JavaScript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after having find how to setup the layout of my project here : [Google Cloud Functions: Project layout for Github publishing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823074/google-cloud-functions-project-layout-for-github-publishing)

On each package.json, in IntelliJ Ultimate (don't know for community edition), I click "run npm install".

Once it's done and the project is reindexed, I have code completion from the libraries.

The downside of this aproach is that you have multiple node_modules folder, about 50MB each, but storage is not that expensive so...